# Parse fixed-width file with RowProcessor (Univocity)

Tags: parsing, fixed-width, univocity

I'm dealing with a fixed-width file with 3 different types of bean :

- Bean 1 (header) : length = 256 ; starts with 0256Q ; one single
  header
- Bean 2 (record) : length = 768 ; starts with 0768T ;
  repeatable
- Bean 3 (footer) : length = 256 ; starts with 0256Z ; one
  single footer

I've tried many options of Univocity but the problem is that the processor.getBeans() methods always return an empty list for each type of bean after the parsing step.

Can anybody help me ?

```
        FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings();
        settings.setAutoConfigurationEnabled(true);
        settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(false);
        settings.setRecordEndsOnNewline(true);
        settings.trimValues(false);
        
        FixedWidthFields header = FixedWidthFields.forParsing(Header0256Q.class);
        FixedWidthFields payment = FixedWidthFields.forParsing(Payment0768T.class);
        FixedWidthFields footer = FixedWidthFields.forParsing(Footer0256Z.class);
```

Lookahead

```
        settings.addFormatForLookahead("0256Q", header);
        settings.addFormatForLookahead("0768T", payment);
        settings.addFormatForLookahead("0256Z", footer);
```

Create a processor per type of record

```
        BeanListProcessor<Header0256Q> headerProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Header0256Q>(Header0256Q.class);
        BeanListProcessor<Payment0768T> paymentProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Payment0768T>(Payment0768T.class);
        BeanListProcessor<Footer0256Z> footerProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Footer0256Z>(Footer0256Z.class);
```

InputValueSwitch

```
        InputValueSwitch inputValueSwitch = new InputValueSwitch();
       
        inputValueSwitch.addSwitchForValue("0256Q", headerProcessor);
        inputValueSwitch.addSwitchForValue("0768T", paymentProcessor);
        inputValueSwitch.addSwitchForValue("0256Z", footerProcessor);
       
        settings.setProcessor(inputValueSwitch);
```

Parsing

```
        FixedWidthParser parser = new FixedWidthParser(settings);
        parser.parse(lFile);
```

Get beans

```
        List<Header0256Q> headerRecords = headerProcessor.getBeans();
        List<Payment0768T> paymentRecords = paymentProcessor.getBeans();
        List<Footer0256Z> footerRecords = footerProcessor.getBeans();
```

Map the file with returned beans

```
        Dtazv dtazv = new Dtazv();
        dtazv.setHeaderRecord(headerRecords.get(0));
        dtazv.setPaymentRecords(paymentRecords);
        dtazv.setFooterRecord(footerRecords.get(0));
```